# Subtracting rasters from each other in batch using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I am trying to calculate the maximum change for each cell in a large amount of rasters. These rasters are number X002,X003 till X150 and I am trying to calculate the change between two consecutive rasters and eventually checking the maximum change per cell by comparing all the changes in the raster values.

I have tried doing this by using a raster iterator to load the rasters into the model, this is the point I get stuck at. The problem is that I can't get to load both raster X002 and X003 at the same time and thus can't calculate the change.